# environment variables in Spring-Boot in email data in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

As you can add environment variables in Spring-Boot in email data in the applitacation.properties file?
In my case I use Linux and configure the environment variables in /etc/environment

It work with

```
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

But it doesn't work with

```
spring.mail.host=${SPRING_MAIL_HOSTNAME}
spring.mail.port=${SPRING_MAIL_PORT}
spring.mail.username=${SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME}
spring.mail.password=${SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD}
```

what is the difference in this?

Comment: There isn't and it should work if they are provided. There is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but you doesn't specify what is not working. To make these properties useful you have to wire the right Spring Boot plugin and obviously use it in your code:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
// wire it in your bean
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender emailSender;
// reference the emailSender and send emails ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, autowired was not configured.